# How can I make a dynamic video player in Actionscript 3.0 in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video, media-player, video-gallery

Need a video player code in Actionscript 3. It is possible to play mp4 format video from any folder in my phone storage location ?

Comment: I think you got down-voted because of your **programming / technical** Question quality. Try to show code of what you've tried so we can help you fix it.  Short sentences are for psychics and/or Google. Consider this : _"Need a..."_ =  No freebie requests allowed, _"It is possible..?"_ = Check the AS3 manual. Anyways I tried to help below, let me know if it works correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Since it's for mobile (using AIR), try using the [**`File`**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html) class. It allows you to browse for files.
You can lock the file browsing to list only **specific format(s)** by using [**`FileFilter`**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileFilter.html).

Read the Adobe guide here : [**`Working with File objects in AIR`**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fe4.html).

Below is an example code you can try. Untested at moment (but modified from this other [**Answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31832095/2057709)).

```
//someGraphic is your own UI element (clicked/tapped) for user to begin file browse
someGraphic.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, browseVideo);

function browseVideo(evt:MouseEvent = null):void 
{
    var vidFiles : FileFilter = new FileFilter("Choose Video", " *.mp4 ; *.flv");

    var file:File = new File();
    file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelected); 
    file.browse([vidFiles]);
}

function onFileSelected(evt:Event):void 
{
    //auto-extract path to give to NS video player
    playVideo(evt.currentTarget.nativePath);
}

function playVideo(video_path:String):void
{
    // using a Video + NetStream object
    var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();
    nc.connect(null);
    var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);
    ns.client = this;
    var video:Video = new Video();
    video.attachNetStream(ns);
    addChild(video);

    ns.play(video_path); //is using auto-extracted path
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help me ,,, That was run correctly in mp4 format..!! ,, Your code is need to chose a video to any location,, But I need to play all video any format from a define Video_folder ,,,, not need to rename such video1.mp4 or video2.flv,,, Help please ..Thanks @VC.One